# react-native ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage

Tags: ios, react-native

I already went through multiple posts and possible fixes, updating different libraries, etc,  trying to fix this issue. I'm not able to identify which library can be the problem.

After running `grep -r UIWebView ./*` on my entire project I get the following references:

```
Binary file ./ios/myApp.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/myuser.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/2HLMFU1M0QDOH/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/2HLMFU1M0QDOH/WebKit-3M3AFHBPPA3AE.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/2HLMFU1M0QDOH/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/LSN2S3SKDOR7/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/LSN2S3SKDOR7/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/3JXWHLC2F21FN/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/3JXWHLC2F21FN/StoreKit-2BRFRHE6RWG9N.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/3JXWHLC2F21FN/WebKit-3M3AFHBPPA3AE.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/3JXWHLC2F21FN/MediaPlayer-2DWL0NXJSGSEI.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/3JXWHLC2F21FN/AuthenticationServices-2OMDOPW4B88YQ.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/3JXWHLC2F21FN/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/QTATJTON98DN/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/QTATJTON98DN/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/3ORDFA6ID13E4/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/3ORDFA6ID13E4/StoreKit-2BRFRHE6RWG9N.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/3ORDFA6ID13E4/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/3ME4E9IB5U5P9/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/3ME4E9IB5U5P9/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/HYMFL0ZADXYU/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/HYMFL0ZADXYU/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/QV6QBQWJIIMP/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/QV6QBQWJIIMP/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/63CGBB6GNV96/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/63CGBB6GNV96/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/3RF3RLE8LIQB1/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/3RF3RLE8LIQB1/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/32KR07SAX72T8/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/32KR07SAX72T8/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/2BETYMPBP3283/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/2BETYMPBP3283/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/1L4O42DWJ17U4/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/1L4O42DWJ17U4/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/FKMGVG9AP453/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/FKMGVG9AP453/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/HSM9QJ30J6H9/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/HSM9QJ30J6H9/WebKit-3M3AFHBPPA3AE.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/HSM9QJ30J6H9/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/1YTWDLDD345AU/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/1YTWDLDD345AU/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/11VRF1GN0DLVL/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/11VRF1GN0DLVL/WebKit-3M3AFHBPPA3AE.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/11VRF1GN0DLVL/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/K0WRRE53RAEC/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/K0WRRE53RAEC/ContactsUI-1IW04PS7QUI2V.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/K0WRRE53RAEC/AVKit-95365SBJXV2.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/K0WRRE53RAEC/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/12BR1L2HFKG5H/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/12BR1L2HFKG5H/WebKit-3M3AFHBPPA3AE.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/12BR1L2HFKG5H/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/32AWGWKTTU8N7/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/32AWGWKTTU8N7/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/1NWED368FL26E/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/1NWED368FL26E/WebKit-3M3AFHBPPA3AE.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/1NWED368FL26E/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/33VZOJ3VJMPOT/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/33VZOJ3VJMPOT/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/2GYY7SQTFG8LT/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/2GYY7SQTFG8LT/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/17IGP4JEFXICD/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/17IGP4JEFXICD/WebKit-3M3AFHBPPA3AE.pcm matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/ModuleCache.noindex/17IGP4JEFXICD/modules.idx matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/records/EJ/UIWebView.h-17DCX353XRLEJ matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-3S29QRIPVEFYO matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTUIManagerObserverCoordinator.o-22HPJ4UKWFA7Y matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTJavaScriptLoader.o-11RB86QLKPUQ matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTCxxBridge.o-1Z4JLGC4A2JLG matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-FX96VU83HAZJ matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTMessageThread.o-1SHDUR12BP2CA matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTObjcExecutor.o-3FJLKJ4H1E06Z matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-3REKR8X6X5HJR matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-1GLKIA3MVEXHR matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTBlobManager.o-1ZMIFQ9QC7XVL matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-1EDOHIVESW9XA matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTFont.o-10NA8K1FCIZN7 matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-2IXFIYW3J6P09 matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTSurfaceRootView.o-3UWDKB7AVRYWY matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-2C1LT6CRGANGZ matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-2X0VJG25OS5O4 matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTLog.o-2UFETOQXACYQX matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTNativeModule.o-4JZ8GLWUDAJC matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTSurfaceView.o-32GQCNCZIGYRU matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTPackagerConnection.o-3C3A7NOWXBRXY matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTCxxUtils.o-44WMPSAXK5TV matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTModuleData.o-18TZIGJBNXAYA matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-ZRB1MOA7NTS8 matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTSurface.o-1FD4E4K1ML22C matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTInspectorDevServerHelper.o-3HU6TZN8CQNS5 matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-1AIOVVY4WE125 matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTSurfaceSizeMeasureMode.o-31M17VYD2LS9V matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-3RRBMNWZLMN11 matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTModuleMethod.o-15N754BVYLCNM matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-15YSGBSZZZFYR matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-2S0VQ7CAWG16W matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-NOBNLTK683QZ matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-3LJ239I3GXXNJ matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/JSCExecutorFactory.o-1O7G83OQN5PHC matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-29WTILYZR6TNM matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTDevSettings.o-1FJXZK40NPTCN matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-2YI8NYFKWA11S matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTHTTPRequestHandler.o-128SB712PEHX4 matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-3BAHSZ72SV8Q6 matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTNetworking.o-21FG3D2P87XIN matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-1D4SR7IZGT5T2 matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTSurfaceHostingView.o-2LFDM1EUEGI1E matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTCxxModule.o-1ASVP8JVVSJTA matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTInspector.o-1ESSZWZOHGUIN matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-36AOCSP5CMY8M matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-32WV1WUKJRCNK matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm-TAH6BWO81AWJ matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Index/DataStore/v5/units/RCTCxxMethod.o-2KL4VQGTNJ49 matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp.app/myApp matches
Binary file ./ios/build/myApp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/myApp matches
./node_modules/react-native/node_modules/ua-parser-js/test/browser-test.json:        "ua"      : "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14A456 QQ/6.5.3.410 V1_IPH_SQ_6.5.3_1_APP_A Pixel/1080 Core/UIWebView NetType/WIFI Mem/26",
./node_modules/react-native/node_modules/fbjs/lib/UserAgent.js.flow:   * - UIWebView
./node_modules/react-native/node_modules/fbjs/lib/UserAgent.js:   * - UIWebView
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/WebView/WebView.android.js:     * If true, use WKWebView instead of UIWebView.
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/WebView/WebView.ios.js:     * If true, use WKWebView instead of UIWebView.
./node_modules/react-native-webview/README.md:- [7.0.1](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/releases/tag/v7.0.1) - Removed UIWebView
./node_modules/rn-spotify-sdk/ios/external/SpotifySDK/CHANGELOG.md:- `-[SPTAuth spotifyWebAuthenticationURL]` returns a https://accounts.spotify.com URL that you should open in a Safari View Controller (or UIWebView if supporting iOS versions prior to 9)
./node_modules/rn-spotify-sdk/ios/external/SpotifySDK/docs/Classes/SPTAuth.html:                <p>Display this URL within a SFSafariViewController on iOS 9 and up, or UIWebView.</p>
./node_modules/rn-spotify-sdk/ios/external/SpotifySDK/docs/Classes/SPTAuthViewController.html:          <p>Removes all authentication related cookies from the UIWebView.</p>
./node_modules/rn-spotify-sdk/ios/external/SpotifySDK/SpotifyAuthentication.framework/Headers/SPTAuth.h: Display this URL within a SFSafariViewController on iOS 9 and up, or UIWebView.
./node_modules/rn-spotify-sdk/ios/external/SpotifySDK/SpotifyAuthentication.framework/Headers/SPTAuthViewController.h: Removes all authentication related cookies from the UIWebView.
Binary file ./node_modules/rn-spotify-sdk/ios/external/SpotifySDK/SpotifyAuthentication.framework/SpotifyAuthentication matches
./node_modules/metro/node_modules/ua-parser-js/test/browser-test.json:        "ua"      : "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14A456 QQ/6.5.3.410 V1_IPH_SQ_6.5.3_1_APP_A Pixel/1080 Core/UIWebView NetType/WIFI Mem/26",
./node_modules/metro/node_modules/fbjs/lib/UserAgent.js.flow:   * - UIWebView
./node_modules/metro/node_modules/fbjs/lib/UserAgent.js:   * - UIWebView
./node_modules/ua-parser-js/test/browser-test.json:        "ua"      : "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14A456 QQ/6.5.3.410 V1_IPH_SQ_6.5.3_1_APP_A Pixel/1080 Core/UIWebView NetType/WIFI Mem/26",
./node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/js/FBShareDialog.js:   * Displays the dialog in a UIWebView within the app.
./node_modules/fbjs/lib/UserAgent.js.flow:   * - UIWebView
./node_modules/fbjs/lib/UserAgent.js:   * - UIWebView
```

a) Should I care about the matches inside `./ios/build/*`?

b) I understand that all the matches I have inside `./node_modules/*` are only comments and doesn't affect the build.

c) Is there another way to find any possible library/dependency that is still using `UIWebView`?

I would really appreciate your help with any kind of hint. Let me know if you need additional information.

Here is a simplified copy of my package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "adm-zip": "^0.4.11",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.0",
    "color": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "number-abbreviate": "^2.0.0",
    "plist": "^2.1.0",
    "progress": "^2.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-moment": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    "react-native-cached-image": "^1.4.3",
    "react-native-code-push": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native-contacts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-native-events": "^1.0.15",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.10.3",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",
    "react-native-flip-toggle-button": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "0.24.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-letter-spacing": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.4",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^4.13.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-music-control": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.8.1",
    "react-native-photo-upload": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-sentry": "^0.42.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-native-video": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-view-overflow": "0.0.3",
    "react-native-webview": "^8.1.2",
    "react-native-wheel-picker": "github:GenomeUS/react-native-wheel-picker",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.22",
    "react-navigation-current-route": "^1.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.5.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "rn-spotify-sdk": "^1.2.12",
    "uglify-es": "^3.2.2",
    "validator": "^10.5.0",
    "vanilla-text-mask": "^5.1.1",
    "xcode": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.5.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.15.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.8.1",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-version": "^2.7.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "uglify-es": "3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: i'd suggest updating your react-native to version 0.6 or above, as version 0.59 still have WebView in it, and you might want to update your rnfbsdk as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this library "rn-spotify-sdk", I end up following what is mentioned here https://github.com/lufinkey/react-native-spotify/issues/168#issuecomment-644950475 => removing SpotifyAuthentication from its dependencies